# What's the difference between :insert and :append?

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a vim command that pastes the code but disable the auto indent. So I find these commands, I can just use one command and paste, then enter the `<Ctrl+C>`, very easy.

However, I don't understand what's the difference between `:insert` and `:append`.

Do they really have the same behavior?

Comment: i believe you are actually looking for `:set paste`.

Comment: @BillLynch Well, It's so good! But I still want to know what's the difference between these commands.

Comment: `:set paste` gets old pretty fast. If you want to use vim plugins then https://github.com/ConradIrwin/vim-bracketed-paste automatically does `set paste` and `set nopaste` when pasting into most terminals. This is also built into neovim.

Comment: @skyler It's working and it's so good, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behaviour of `:insert` and `:append` is not the same.

```
:insert
```

Insert text before the cursor

```
:append
```

Insert text after the cursor

From `:h append`

append({lnum}, {expr})
                *append()*

```
    When {expr} is a |List|: Append each item of the |List| as a
    text line below line {lnum} in the current buffer.
    Otherwise append {expr} as one text line below line {lnum} in
    the current buffer.
    {lnum} can be zero to insert a line before the first one.
```

Comment: I understand, like `a` and `i`. Thank you :)

Comment: Ya. Analogous to a and i.